# RenderPartial and popup modal MVC C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, popup, modal-dialog, renderpartial

I have some code in Index view

```
@foreach (var item in Model){
<tr><td>......</td>
    <td><button class="success" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#detailsModal" >details</button>
        <div class="modal fade" id="detailsModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="detailsModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
             @{Html.RenderPartial("_Details", item);}
        </div></td></tr>}
```

but after click my button on different rows, popup show always first item of database. How can I change it?

Controller

```
        public ActionResult Details(int? id)
    {
        DBase dbase = new DBase();
        dbase = db.DBase.Find(id);
        return PartialView("_Details", dbase);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `multiple` modals declared in your HTML with same `ID` due to your `foreach` loop.

So it only uses the first modal element it found. To fix this give each of your modal a unique ID.

So you would change `data-target="#detailsModal"` and `id="detailsModal"` by adding index to it so it would be like `id="detailsModal-1"` etc